# The instance member 'variable' cant be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have this class which accept docID by passing the value when calling the DatabaseService class.

However when i am trying to put this docID variable into my firebase query. It shows that my ${docID} is an instance member and cant be accessed in an initialier. Pleasae help me.

Data passed in like this

```
Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => announcementDetail(announcementlist.id),
                ),
```

announcementDetail class accepet the passed value

```
class announcementDetail extends StatelessWidget {

  final String docID;
  announcementDetail(this.docID);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<List <Announcement>>.value(
      value: DatabaseService(uid: ' ', docID: docID).announcementDetailList,
      initialData: [],
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Home'),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          elevation: 0.0,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Announcement_Detail_List(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

DatabaseService class accepts the value passed from announcementDetail class

```
class DatabaseService {

  final String? uid;
  final String? docID;
  final bool toggleDate = false;
  DatabaseService({ required this.uid, required this.docID});

  final Query<Map<String, dynamic>> getAnnouncementDetail = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('announcementlist').where('id', isEqualTo: '${docID}');
  
  
  //announcementdetail list from snapshot
  List <Announcement> _announcementDetailListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
      return Announcement(
          id: doc.id,
          title: doc.get('title') ?? '',
          dateTime: doc.get('dateTime') ?? '',
          content: doc.get('content') ?? '',
          aType: doc.get('announcementType') ?? '',
          aLevel: doc.get('announcementLevel') ?? ''
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  // get announcementdetail stream
  Stream<List <Announcement>> get announcementDetailList {
    return getAnnouncementDetail.snapshots()
        .map(_announcementDetailListFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

error part is here is DatabaseService Class

```
final Query<Map<String, dynamic>> getAnnouncementDetail = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('announcementlist').where('id', isEqualTo: '${docID}');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use the `docID` field of your `DatabaseService` class in the initializer of a field, which runs before its constructor is called. Since the constructor is where `this.docID` gets its value, you cannot use this value before the constructor has run.

The solution is to initialize the `getAnnouncementDetail` field inside the constructor:

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String? uid;
  final String? docID;
  final bool toggleDate = false;
  late Query<Map<String, dynamic>> getAnnouncementDetail;

  DatabaseService({ required this.uid, required this.docID}) {
    getAnnouncementDetail = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('announcementlist').where('id', isEqualTo: '${docID}');
  }
  ...
```